# What are some possible PhD research areas based on these course pairs?

Tags: research

Update:
This question has been closed by the votes of 5 privileged users because it does not meet stackexchange's guidelines (it is considered off-topic). For questions about choosing a course / career / academic program you should reach out to faculty and individuals at your institution who can better help you figure out potential career paths / research topics. I myself will reach out to my advisor again and will see if he can help me see what research areas each of these fall into/ what options I have.
That being said, it seems this has been categorized as me asking for help with choosing my courses/career path. This might be a misunderstanding, as I was asking what research areas match specific courses, not asking for help deciding on which courses to take. Regardless, that is probably also considered off-topic, and so I will keep any questions regarding research strictly between me and my university.

I just finished my first semester in a PhD program in Pure and Applied Mathematics and I need to figure out what research area I want to focus on.

The crux of the issue is that I need to figure out what courses I need to take. These courses should match my research area, so I have to figure out my area of research first.

I originally was very interested in modeling, predictions, and statistics, and machine learning, but due to my performance in my courses this semester (B, B+, A) my adviser suggested maybe considering a different area of focus, stating that he thinks I will struggle to pass the qual. This has been a rather crazy semester, and was my first semester in the program and working as a Teaching Assistant (which was a lot of fun).

Even if this still were my main focus, my area of research needs to be more specific.
Moreover, my school seems to offer a few fixed pairs of courses that have good synergy that you would take and then have on the qualifying exam. I have to take two pairs of them I believe. I might be able to customize it somewhat but I would need to have a very good grasp on what area / problem I want to work on.

Those pairs are:

- Probability / Mathematical Statistics or Probability / Stochastic Processes
- Nonlinear Optimization / Dyn. Prog. & Reinforcement Learning (Something about machine learning, etc)
- Numerical Analysis / ODEs
- PDEs / Complex Analysis
- Discrete Math (& Combinatorial stuff) / Graph Theory
- Algebra-focused courses, but I was told they have little synergy with the other courses and are thus not very recommended.

Rather than determining my area of research so I can choose two matching pairs of courses to focus on, I thought it might be easier to go in reverse, to come here and ask the community what areas of research match these pairs. I was hoping I could get some insight into possible areas of research and what makes them interesting/beautiful/exciting. If you have any other areas to consider I would love to hear about them, as I think I can probably customize my focus (assuming the courses are being offered).
If you want to know more about my course history / timeline, please let me know. I removed it from this post in the interest of being concise.
Please let me know your thoughts / ideas on possible research areas, and please share any links/resources you would recommend to help me decide.
I am very grateful for your time and help!

(P.S. I am still leaning towards a Probability and Nonlinear Optimization based focus, but I believe I would have to do a lot of studying / asking Professors for help to get where I need to be with those subjects)

Comment: This is just my opinion, but changing your research area to avoid struggling on quals seems suboptimal. I think you should ask on Academia stack exchange to get a second opinion regarding your advisors suggestion.

Comment: @JacobMaibach Thank you for your suggestion, I will post there too and see what people suggest. On a side note, I did not mention this in my above post (due to not wanting to make it overly complicated), but I only have a bachelors degree and as such I have a little flexibility with when I take the qual. I did not know this until halfway through the semester though, and if I had known I would have liked to take some courses to solidify my background a bit. I am not sure if this flexibility changes anything, but I wanted to mention it as well.

Comment: Technical point – the question was **not** closed by a moderator, it was closed by the votes of five users who have earned the privilege of casting such votes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for that clarification. I will edit my post to be more accurate. I think the moderation system could use some improvements. Closing my question is certainly valid, but the main reason given for it being closed was not, and upon reading through the guidelines (as suggested) for this website I did not find any being violated. I think the spirit of the reason behind why it was closed makes sense, and I have no qualms with it being closed, but the reason for it being closed should be accurate. Between 5 privileged users an accurate explanation is not much to ask for.

Comment: Unfortunately the software offers only a very few options as reasons for closure, and users who vote to close have to choose the least inaccurate one. Sometimes, they leave comments which give a better idea of the actual reason(s) for closure.